# I want to decrypt a text when I don't know it's algorithm and key?

Tags: cryptography

"Ltqd gggzdi kgkniwpa tr hmze fwoifww ub tkfubpw szl ciasvtxwe bsi wzmckq fplx uaupw xdwx xzq rzc gr klvazo elazod efp bsi uavqmvqvni az bsi kqvdi ltie cgg inxmmtwc umv nejq aeyxr."

Comment: The plaintext could be absolutely any message with Kolmogorov complexity (i.e. either length or compressed length) no greater than the length of the ciphertext.  Good luck enumerating those and deciding between them.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like Vigenere cipher.

Try this:

http://www.dcode.fr/vigenere-cipher

**EDIT:** Here is the result. It is indeed Vigenere cipher.

"This course succeeds in part because it ignites and reignites the energy that comes from the joy of caring things and the confidence in the sense that you actually can care stuff"

**Key:** Smile